# SubDomain not work with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**Main domain:** www.kientrucht.com

**Folder:** public_html/

File: index.php

File htaccess: **public_html/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php 

RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?com=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html/$ index.php?com=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html/p=([0-9]+)$ index.php?com=$1&p=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html/keyword=(.*)/p=([0-9]+)$ index.php?com=$1&keyword=$2&p=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html/keyword=(.*)/$ index.php?com=$1&keyword=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html/keyword=(.*)$ index.php?com=$1&keyword=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?com=$1&lang=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?com=$1&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?com=$1&idl=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/p=([0-9]+)$ index.php?com=$1&idl=$2&p=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/p=([0-9]+)$ index.php?com=$1&idl=$2&idcat=$3&p=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?com=$1&idl=$2&idcat=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?com=san-pham&idl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/&p=([0-9]+)$ index.php?com=san-pham&idl=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html/p=([0-9]+)$ index.php?com=san-pham&idl=$1&idcat=$2&p=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?com=san-pham&idl=$1&idcat=$2 [L]
```

**Subdomain:** beta.kientrucht.com

**Folder:** public_html/_beta

File: public_html/_beta/index.html

Can not access subdomain! Automatically recognized as MainDomain (kientrucht.com on public_html/ not public_html/_beta/)!

How to edit current **public_html/.htaccess** file for any file and path on subdomain working normally ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the .htaccess file is inherited in the subdirectories.

You have to create a new .htaccess file in the _beta folder with the redirect on the _beta/index.html.